# How to change initial condition in while loop

Tags: python, while-loop, do-while

I am entering a while loop with a specific initial condition (m=0). Inside the while loop I have a for loop which needs to break if a spec. condition is reached, here if my growth rate is >= 20%.

If this condition is reached I want to leave the for loop and use `i` to set the new `m`. Then I want to do a new for loop and again leave the loop if the condition is reached and use the new `i` for `m`.

I tried with `m+=i` but this sums up the `i`'s, which I don't want. I want the every new `i` is used for `m`. Please find below the code

```
nvdia=pd.read_csv(r"/NVDA.csv",sep=",").round(1)
nvdia["Date"]=pd.to_datetime(nvdia["Date"])
nvdia=nvdia.set_index(nvdia["Date"])

nvdia=nvdia.drop("Date",1)
nvdia=nvdia.loc["2017-07-01":"2018-07-01"]

#nvdia["Close"].plot()

m=0
i=0
while m<len(nvdia.index):
  m+=i ###This is what I use but it is wrong. If I use i=m the loop is goes infinity, which really is  strange
  for i in range(m,len(nvdia.index)):
    percentage_growth=100*(nvdia["Close"].values[i]/nvdia["Close"].values[m]-1)
    if percentage_growth>=20:
        break
```

Comment: Try using `m=i` right before `break` inside your `if` statement

Comment: how can this code even run? When you reach m+=i it should raise an error cause i is not defined yet

Comment: @Edoardo: ye you are right, I also set i=0 before the while condition.

Comment: @Zmf: I think I used m=i after the break statement. Let me try it. I will keep you updated :)

Comment: Do you even need to lose a loop for this? Can you explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: Yes I can explain. What I want to get is: suppose you start a t=t0 with an investment. Now you gor forward in time and checks when you reach +20%. If you reach this point t=t1 you take this point as new starting point and goes forward and checks when you reach -5%. From this point you go again and look for +20%. You repeat this process until you reach the last point

Answer (score 0):

@zmf: Thank you it helped. However I needed to add an additional break statement to leave the while loop, since my condition m

In case someone might have one day same/similar issue, here is the solution

```
m=0
while m<=len(nvidia.index):
  for i in range(m,len(nvidia.index)):
    percentage_growth=100*(nvidia["Close"].values[i]/nvidia["Close"].values[m]-1)
    if percentage_growth>=20:
        m=i
        print(m,percentage_growth)
        break
    else:
        percentage_growth=100*(nvidia["Close"].values[i]/nvidia["Close"].values[m]-1)

  if i+1==len(nvidia.index):
      break
```